# Order by best match for multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to order a query by the best match querying multiple fields:

Here is an example

```
Select name, surname, charindex('jh',name) as s1, charindex('br', surname) as s2 
order by s1, s2
```

In this way the query is ordered for all s1 then for s2.

What I would like to achieve is to order by s1 and s2 values together, then all the '1' result of s1 and s2 go first, then all the '2' results of both fields and so on.

The query is generated by an ORM so I need a construction logic that is valid for every situation and not one that requires the creation of temporary tables or anything like that.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help us help you. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's put s1 and s2 in a subquery so we can use them later:

```
Select name, surname, q1.s1, q1.s2
from 
    yourtable
    cross apply
    (select
         charindex('jh',name) as s1
        ,charindex('br', surname) as s2 
    ) as q1
```

To do what you want, let's create a new column s1_equals_s2 which does what you say, then sort by that one first:

```
Select name, surname, q1.s1, q1.s2
from 
    yourtable
    cross apply
    (select
         charindex('jh',name) as s1
        ,charindex('br', surname) as s2 
    ) as q1
    cross apply(select case when s1=s2 then 1 else 0 end as s1_equals_s2) as q2
order by q2.s1_equals_s2 desc,q1.s1,q1.s2
```

Comment: Your solution works but is not usable for the use I have to make of it. The query is generated by an ORM and returns an object, so I cannot use subqueries. I believe that what I want to achieve is not possible through a simple query.